# SDN 4- findAll(1) return duplicated results

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using SDN 4 with Java 8.

I'm testing this code.
I have two owner and each owner have one truck.

```
repository.findAll(1).forEach(owner -> {
    logger.info(owner.toString());
});
```

I expect logging two rows(owner). however It prints 4 rows.(twice each owner)

```
repository.findAll(0).forEach(owner -> {
    logger.info(owner.toString());
});
```

I changed depth to 0. It print 2 rows that i expect.

Why first code print 4 rows? Is it spec something i didn't know?
When I run first code. It use this CQL

```
MATCH (n:`Owner`) WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p
```

and I testing this query to browser, It's show Owner and related truck.
when I changed rows view mode. It return 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is that a custom depth brings in related nodes, so the number of paths increase. The number of distinct nodes of type Owner were not returned correctly.

But, this issue was fixed- please upgrade to use neo4j-ogm 1.1.5 or [SDN 4.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.1.0.M1/reference/html/) (4.1.0.M1).

Comment: Can I know change list for SDN 4.1?